# C# ¿Cómo asignarle el valor de las propiedades de un objeto a una variable?

Tags: c#, poo

Teniendo el siguiente método donde asigno las propiedades:

```
public struct Address
{
    public string Street;
    public string City;
    public string State;
    public string Zip;
    public string Country;
    public AddressType Type;

}

public void SetHomeAddress(Address myVar)
{
    myVar.Street = "Calle A";
    myVar.City = "Ciudad B";
    myVar.State = "Estado C";
    myVar.Zip = "123455";
    myVar.Country = "Ciudad D";

}
```

donde además creé una propiedad de solo lectura:

```
Address HomeAddress
{ get; private set; }
```

Todo esto es del tipo `struct` que desarrollé, el cual es `Address`

Pero no encuentro la manera de asignarle los valores que tengo en mi metodo `setHomeAddress` a la variable `HomeAddress`

De cierta forma debería quedar `HomeAddress = "Calle A Ciudad B Estado C 123455 Ciudad D"`

Hay una manera para asignar esos valores a la variable?

Gracias, agradecería su apoyo!!

Comment: Ten en cuenta que las estructuras en C# (`struct`) son un tipo de datos de valor [`Value Type`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types). Esto significa que al pasarlo como parámetro, el método recibe una copia y por lo tanto las asignaciones que hace el método `SetHomeAddress(Address myVar)` se hacen en una copia y no alteran la estructura original. Prueba cambiando `Address` a una clase y me comentas el resultado.

Answer (score 2):

Estás pasando el parámetro como valor, has de pasarlo como referencia:

```
public void SetHomeAddress(ref Address myVar)
{
    myVar.Street = "Calle A";
    myVar.City = "Ciudad B";
    myVar.State = "Estado C";
    myVar.Zip = "123455";
    myVar.Country = "Ciudad D";
}
```

Para obtener la dirección completa, podríamos crear una propiedad en la propia estructura que nos devuelva dicho dato:

```
public struct Address
    {
        public string Street;
        public string City;
        public string State;
        public string Zip;
        public string Country;
        public AddressType Type;

        // Para obtener la dirección completa
        public string FullAddress
        {
            get
            {
                return string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}", Street, 
                                                            City, 
                                                            State,
                                                            Zip,
                                                            Country);
            }
        }
    }
```

Así de esta forma obtienes la dirección competa:

```
Address miDireccion;
SetHomeAddress(ref miDireccion);

string HomeAddress = miDireccion.FullAddress;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!, pero de la forma que pueda settear mi variable HomeAddress  a esos valores, hay una manera? dentro de ese método.

Comment: Lo puedes hacer en la propia struct, te amplio la respuesta.